# ArrayList throwing "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException"

Tags: java, arrays, string, arraylist

I know from reading other questions on the forumn that Array indexing is causing the problem, but I don't know any way around it. I commented where the throw happens. The whole throw is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 35
at assignment4.AnagramUtil.getLargestAnagramGroup(AnagramUtil.java:82)
at assignment4.AnagramTester.main(AnagramTester.java:36)
```

If anyone has any ideas how I can make this work, let me know. Also, I don't think any more of my methods are relevant in solving this but I can put them here if needed.

```
    /*areAnagrams
     * parameters: sorted strings x & y
     * returns boolean
     * implements sort method
     */
    public static boolean areAnagrams(String x, String y)
    {
        if(sort(x).equals(sort(y)))
            return true;
        return false;
    }


    /*
     * This function takes a string array and finds the largest anagram group.
     * AnagramComparator.insertionSort() sorts the array by placing anagrams together,
     * so no sorting is needed.
     * I use ArrayList because I want to be able to freely add to the string array.
     * returns a new String[]
     */
    public static String[] getLargestAnagramGroup(String[] input)
    {
        String[] s=input;

        AnagramComparator.insertionSort(s, new AnagramComparator());

          int largestCount = 0, tempCount=1;
          ArrayList<String> largest= new ArrayList<String>();
          ArrayList<String> temp= new ArrayList<String>();

          for(int i=0; i<s.length; i++)
          {
              //since it's already sorted, we need only to compare.
              //add 
              temp.add(s[i]);
                                            //Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 35
              if (areAnagrams(s[i],s[i+1]))  //at assignment4.AnagramUtil.getLargestAnagramGroup(AnagramUtil.java:82)
              {
                  //add s[i+1] to array list
                  temp.add(s[i+1]);
                  tempCount++;
              }
              else
              {

                    //if tempcount> largestcount, empty contents of largest and make temp largest

                    if (tempCount>largestCount)
                    {
                        if(!largest.isEmpty())
                            largest.clear();
                        largest=temp;
                    largestCount=tempCount; 
                    }
                    //reset tempcount
                    tempCount=1;
              }

          }

     String[] result= new String[largest.size()];

     for (int j=0;j<largest.size();j++)
         result[j]=largest.get(j);
                return result;


    }
```

Comment: What happens with this line when i = length-1;  temp.add(s[i+1]);

Comment: Why do you need `String[] s=input;`

Comment: It still throws. It might help, I don't know.

Comment: I use String[] s= input so the insertionsort doesn't affect the input.

Comment: @JawshBivens references do not work that way. `String[] s = input` copies the reference, not the array - now `input` and `s` both contain references to the one array.

Answer (score 3):

your problem is here:

```
areAnagrams(s[i],s[i+1])
```

this will fail when `i = s.length - 1` because of `i + 1` (when `i = s.length` it is out of bounds, as `length` returns the number of elements, yet array index starts at 0)

change

```
for(int i=0; i<s.length; i++)
```

to

```
for(int i=0; i<s.length - 1; i++)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try changing this line:

```
for(int i=0; i<s.length; i++)
```

to this:

```
 for(int i=0; i<s.length-1; i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a loop

```
for(int i=0; i<s.length; i++) {...
```

which means that for the maximum allowable value of `i`, `s[i]` will be the last element in `s`.

But within the loop you are referencing `s[i + 1]`, which is past the end of `s`.